# Integrating h.265 Video Codec into VLC player

Tags: vlc, libvlc, video-player, hevc

I have a task of adding a new h.265 decoder support to VLC player. So I have downloaded, build the VLC source code in Ubuntu 14.0 and  my  Decoder take input as video encoded file or NAL unit and output Decoded picture. But I am not understanding how VLC will communicate with Decoder? What are the detail step to write module?

Comment: Hey man can you please tell me which version of Ubuntu are you using. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I get some build error. Please have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969915/build-vlc-for-android-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: H265 is already supported in VLC since a long time, so it is probably not necessary to add another decoder unless you want to use your own library. A decoder module consists of an open, a close and a decode callback which provides you with input data and you return the decoded picture. What happens in between is your business and depends on the decoder you are using.

Comment: @feepk Ans this question your comment is correct....it may help to other, as I got .